# Weird lines on mesh after exiting sculpt mode

Tags: modeling, sculpting

[image]

Hey there, does anyone know why i get these weird lines all over my mesh after exiting sculpt mode? Shading is set to smooth and normals are facing outwards. I also tried to put a subsurf modifier on top of it. Nothing helped. :/

Answer (score 1):

Simply the multires modifier wasn't set high enough. Another level and an overall smooth fixed it. Still strange tho since i set preview and sculpt to the same level.